# Update value of key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to multiply the value of all 'imdb' keys by 10 and update the value. In the code below when I print_r $horrorMovies it just shows I have created a new array with the required amounts. Its almost there if i do

```
 $horrorMovies[0]['imdb'] = $imdbPercent;
```

But the values just get written to the first nested array.

Im not sure how to make this work with foreach, if it is possible.

```
function imdbMultiply($n) {
    return($n['imdb'] * 10);
}

$horrorMovies = array(
    array(
    "title" => "The babadook",
    "imdb"  => 6.8,
    "rotten" => 98
    ),
    array(
    "title" => "The shining",
    "imdb" => 8.4,
    "rotten" => 87
)

);



$imdbPercent = array_map("imdbMultiply", $horrorMovies);

$horrorMovies['imdb'] = $imdbPercent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code:

1. Your `imdbMultiply` function needs to return the `$n` array, but modified so the `imdb` key is multiplied by 10.
2. `array_map` returns the new array, so you should set `$horrorMovies` to the result of `array_map`

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
function imdbMultiply ($n) {
    $n['imdb'] *= 10;
    return $n;
}

$horrorMovies = array_map('imdbMultiply', $horrorMovies);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//original data
$horrorMovies = array(
    array(
    "title" => "The babadook",
    "imdb"  => 6.8,
    "rotten" => 98
    ),
    array(
    "title" => "The shining",
    "imdb" => 8.4,
    "rotten" => 87
)
);

//define "transformation" function, note that the argument is passed via reference
function imdbMultiply(&$n) {
    $n['imdb'] *= 10;
}

//one option is to use foreach and then unset the reference to the
//last array element
foreach($horrorMovies as &$v){
    $v['imdb'] *= 10;
}
unset($v);
print_r($horrorMovies);

//alternatively, one might apply the "transformation" function
//directly to each array element without the need to create a copy
array_walk($horrorMovies, "imdbMultiply");
print_r($horrorMovies);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you expect, your imdbMultiply() function should be the following to be used with [array_map](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php) :

```
function imdbMultiply($n) {
    $n['imdb'] *= 10;
    return $n;
}
```

Is it what you expect ?

Another idea is to use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php) function, but you should define your imdbMultiply() function like this :

```
function imdbMultiply(&$n) {
    $n['imdb'] *= 10;
}
```

The usage of array_walk is different :

```
array_walk($horrorMovies, "imdbMultiply"); 
var_dump($horrorMovies);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just need to rework the function as in your top example.

Answer (score 0):

You can just foreach the subarray[imdb] items.

```
$horrorMovies = array(
    array(
    "title" => "The babadook",
    "imdb"  => 6.8,
    "rotten" => 98
    ),
    array(
    "title" => "The shining",
    "imdb" => 8.4,
    "rotten" => 87
)

);


foreach($horrorMovies as &$subarray){
    $subarray["imdb"] *= 10;
}

var_dump($horrorMovies);
```

https://3v4l.org/ub40E

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go into a loop and change the 'imdb' values, add the next 
*for* loop to your code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($horrorMovies); $i++){
    $horrorMovies[$i]['imdb']*=10;
}
```